# Several conditional statements in WHERE clause and Short-Circuit OR

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to write SQL query that has several conditional statements in the `WHERE` clause.
Pseudo code looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable 
WHERE
  //Either one or both of below statements can evaluate to TRUE,
  //to evaluate the the entire WHERE predicate to be TRUE. 
  //However, both Ifs need to be checked and not skipped.
  If(@ProductID <> 1) THEN (T1 AND T2) 
  If(@ProductType = 2) THEN (T3 AND T4)
```

The problem for me is the WHERE statement. `WHERE 1 = (CASE....THEN 1) ELSE 0` doesn't work, because as soon as the first `If` statements is executed, it end the `CASE`, but I need to execute both `If` statements. The other way,`WHERE ((@ProductID <> 1) AND (T1 AND T2)) OR ((@ProductType = 2) AND (T3 AND T4))` will not work either, because SQL Server optimizer can short circuit the `OR` and skip the second `If` statement.

**EDIT**: To clear some confusion. T1-4 are predicates. I want to evaluate the entire predicate in `WHERE` clause to be TRUE, whenever one or all `If` statements (and it's predicate in `THEN`) are evaluated to TRUE. But, at the same time, I want all `If`s to be checked. Just like in sequential code, when sequence of `If` statements are evaluated.

Comment: I have no idea what your comment on short-circuiting is supposed to mean.  The end result is the same.

Comment: `(T1 AND T2)` how is this a condition?

Comment: There is no "short circuit" in tsql. Stop trying to prematurely optimize. Nor can you use IF in a where clause. Perhaps you should start by searching on "case in where".

Comment: @DaleK I assume that `T1` is shorthand for "conditional term 1", a comparison that has a boolean result, so `T1` might be `(fieldX = fieldY)`

Comment: @ChrisLatta probably correct... but best if OP doesn't expect us to make assumptions.

Comment: @DaleK Agreed. The discussion around "need to execute both IF statements" makes me concerned that `T3` might be a stored procedure that returns a boolean result but also performs some side effect function that prepares the data.

Comment: I just made clarification. See EDIT. After rereading my original post, I think I see where the confusion comes from.

Comment: Short circuiting does NOT lead to functionally different behaviour (queries can not have side effects; so, whether one half of an OR is evaluated is skipped is impossible to see afterwards). The result of the logical expression will always be correct. Voting to close as no evidence has been presented that the op is actually experiencing a real issue (for example, demonstrating problematic behaviour with example data and a real sql query).

Comment: The edit also makes no sense. `IF` statements can not be used in `WHERE` clauses. `CASE` expressions can be, but they can not have predicates in there return clauses. The question is full of fallacies, misunderstandings, or miscommunication. Until an MRE is added, the question is impossible to provide a sensible answer to; https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include the conditional in the boolean comparison of your T* terms:

```
WHERE
  (@ProductID <> 1 AND T1 AND T2)
  OR
  (@ProductType = 2 AND T3 AND T4)
```

Comment: OR can be short-circuit by optimizer, so it can skip the second `(@ProductType = 2 AND T3 AND T4)`, but I need it to be checked as well.

Comment: It will only short circuit if the first conditional is true, because if the first is true then it doesn't need to check the rest of the WHERE clause - the result will be true. However, if the first conditional is false, it will go on to test the rest of the WHERE clause to see if there is a true result

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how `T1 AND T2` and `T3 AND T4` translate into conditions. But to include both conditions you flip the logic around to allow you to use `AND`.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE
-- So if @ProductID = 1 we short circuit out of this branch else we apply (T1 AND T2)
(@ProductID = 1 OR (T1 AND T2))
AND
-- And if @ProductID != 2 we short circuit out of this branch else we apply (T3 AND T4)
(@ProductID <> 2 OR (T3 AND T4))
```

Even after your edits I still believe this is correct - I suggest you create a minimal reproducible example to demonstrate. But let me try and clarify. So your original first line is `If(@ProductID <> 1) THEN (T1 AND T2)` now if you look at my first line, if `@ProductId = 1` then the first line is automatically true without testing `T1 AND T2` - which is the logic you want, because you only want to carry out tests `T1 AND T2` when `@ProductId <> 1`.

So the first line is true either if `@ProductId = 1` OR if `T1 AND T2` - which is exactly what you ask for (as written).

So your key requirement is to ensure the second line is tested as well, hence you must use an AND. And then the same principle applies to the second line. You carry out the tests `T3 AND T4` if `If(@ProductType = 2)` and not otherwise. Because the second condition is automatically true when `@ProductType <> 2` so ignoring `T3 AND T4` in that case.

Comment: Dale, maybe I missing something. But, if `(@ProductID = 1 OR (T1 AND T2))` turns out to be FALSE , then `AND` in the middle will evaluate the entire to FALSE, therefore entire predicate in `WHERE` will evaluate to FALSE. 
What I'm looking for, it also evaluate the entire predicate as TRUE in `WHERE`, whenever one or both statements  `(@ProductID = 1 OR (T1 AND T2))`,  `(@ProductID <> 2 OR (T3 AND T4))` evaluates to be TRUE. ` I.e it more of the cumulative action. 

If I were to replace `AND` with `OR` then, `OR` can short circuit and skip `(@ProductID <> 2 OR (T3 AND T4))`

Comment: See the  "EDIT" in my question. I made some clarifications.

Comment: @newprint - did you actually try this? I appreciate the logic is a bit complex, but it does exactly what you ask. Let me clarify in the question.

Comment: If my clarifications still don't make it clear (and if doesn't work when you try it), then you need to create a [mre] with sample data, the query and expected results.